# jQuery numeric increment decrements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make increment decrements  through jQuery.

```js
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("div.inputQty").append('<div class="inc add">&#43;</div><div class="dec add">&#8722;</div>');

    jQuery(".add").click(function() {
        var jQueryadd = jQuery(this);
        var oldValue = jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val();
  var newVal = 0;
    
        if (jQueryadd.text() == "›") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
       // AJAX save would go here
     } else {
       // Don't allow decrementing below zero
       if (oldValue > 1) {
           newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
           // AJAX save would go here
       }
    if(oldValue == 1){
     newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
     }
     }
     jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    });
 

});
```

```html
<div class="inputQty">
        <span class="up">&#43;</span>         
        <input type="text" maxlength="6" name="oa_quantity" class="input-quantity"  value="1"/> 
        <span class="down">&#8722;</span>
</div>
```

But it not working. Please help me to solve this

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/suman17018/wLvpavug/) is the demo

Comment: One doubt. You already have + and - in html. Why again you are adding through javascript??

Comment: in html i am using the tag, and in js define their function. i am not sure this is correct. please help me to do this.

Comment: I don't think you need to append again in `jquery/javascript`. You can just add changes to you already existing elements if you want. Or else just directly add class to your `+` and `-` and @huggilou's answer might help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("div.inputQty").append('<div class="inc add">&#43;</div><div class="dec add">&#8722;</div>');

    jQuery(".add, .up, .down").click(function() {
        var jQueryadd = jQuery(this);
        var oldValue = jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val();
        var newVal = 0;

        if (jQueryadd.text() == "+") {
           newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
          // AJAX save would go here
        } else {
          // Don't allow decrementing below zero
          if (oldValue > 1) {
              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
              // AJAX save would go here
          }
          if(oldValue == 1){
              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
              }
        }
        jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    });


});
```

i think its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to load the jQuery library in your test.

Also, you don't need this line `jQuery("div.inputQty").append('<div class="inc add">&#43;</div><div class="dec add">&#8722;</div>');` as long as you already have the `up` and `down` spans.

The working js code would be:

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery('.add').on('click', function() {
        var jQueryadd = jQuery(this);
        var oldValue = jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val();
        var newVal = 0;

        if (jQueryadd.hasClass('up')) {
           newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
          // AJAX save would go here
        } else {
          // Don't allow decrementing below zero
          if (oldValue > 1) {
              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
              // AJAX save would go here
          }
          if(oldValue == 1){
              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
          }
        }
        jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    }); 

});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="inputQty">
        <span class="up add">&#43;</span>
        <input type="text" maxlength="6" name="oa_quantity" class="input-quantity"  value="1"/> 
        <span class="down add">&#8722;</span>
</div>
```

See the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wLvpavug/4/)

Comment: thank you for reply and it really helpful. one more thing. see here http://jsfiddle.net/suman17018/5wkavhcd/  . i need the box like this +   −.  with increment decrement function.how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an event to a dynamic new element. In this case you have to use a [delegated event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
jQuery(".inputQty").on('click', '.add', function() {
    //will work with dynamic elements
}
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wLvpavug/5/

Answer (score 0):

I added parseFloat in var "oldValue" line and lastLine of .click function

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("div.inputQty").append('<div class="inc add">ADDDDDDDDD</div><div class="dec add">&#8722;</div>');

    jQuery(".add").click(function() {
        var jQueryadd = jQuery(this);

        var oldValue = parseFloat(jQueryadd.parent().find("input").val());
        console.log(oldValue);
        var newVal = 0;

        if (jQueryadd.text() == "›") {
           newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
          // AJAX save would go here
        } else {
          // Don't allow decrementing below zero
          if (oldValue > 1) {
              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
              // AJAX save would go here
          }
          if(oldValue == 1){
              newVal = parseFloat(oldValue);
              }
        }
        jQuery(".input-quantity").val(newVal);
    });


});
```

check this out >> 
http://jsfiddle.net/ChoHongRae/nqk6ns4v/